# ARSessionConfiguration unresolved in Xcode 9 GM

Tags: ios, arkit, xcode9

I have created an `ARKit` project using a beta version of Xcode 9, which I was able to run on my real device without issues.
Yesterday, I upgraded to Xcode 9 GM, and without touching anything, Xcode shows multiple errors, saying it does not know `ARSessionConfiguration` i.e.:

> Use of undeclared type 'ARSessionConfiguration'

and:

> Use of undeclared type 'ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration'

...for this code:

```
let session = ARSession()
var sessionConfig: ARSessionConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
```

I have imported `ARKit` and am using the `ARSCNViewDelegate` in my ViewController.
When opening the project from the beta version of Xcode, it does not show the errors and I can again run the app on my phone.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration` has been deprecated and renamed to `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`: [See here](http://codeworkshop.net/objc-diff/sdkdiffs/ios/11.0b5/ARKit.html)

Also, `ARSessionConfiguration` has been deprecated and renamed to `ARConfiguration`, which is now an abstract base class.

Use [AROrientationTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arorientationtrackingconfiguration) when you don't want world tracking, instead of using a generic ARConfiguration. Thus:

```
let configuration = AROrientationTrackingConfiguration()
```

You can also check if world tracking is supported on a device:

```
if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {
   configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
}
else  {
   configuration = AROrientationTrackingConfiguration()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 9 GM, looks like ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration has been renamed to ARWorldTrackingConfiguration:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration

Reference to this change:

https://github.com/markdaws/arkit-by-example/issues/7

ARSessionConfiguration has been renamed to ARConfiguration:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration

Comment: Close, but not quite — `ARConfiguration` is now an abstract base class. If you were using `ARSessionConfiguration` directly (for 3DOF-only tracking) in betas,  [`AROrientationTrackingConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arorientationtrackingconfiguration) is what you need now.